# SQL server periodically gets disconnected

Tags: sql-server

Our environment is:
Windows Server 2003, Service Pack 2
SQL Server Express 2005
SQLServer JDBC driver 1.2 (also tried Jtds)
Sun JDK 1.6 (we tried this on JDK 1.5 as well)
There is no virus protection software on the host, and no firewall is enabled.

We have Web application deployed in JBOSS 4.0.2.
Our problem is that the JDBC connection to SQL server periodically gets disconnected, and then we can't reconnect to the database at all, unless we physically restart the server on which JBOSS deployed.

we are getting following error in log.

> Software caused connect on abort: recv
>   failed

Note: We are able to connect to database using sample java test class.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated, as this is a serious, mission-criticial problem for us right now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the SQL Server using Management Studio? If so how many connections are open?

Do you close your connections after querying?

What does the Task Manager tell, service still running; mem/cpu usage.

Its a long shot but do you have enough disk space on C: and data-drive?